# How can I to link my post creator page to the other pages in Python?

Tags: python, django

I am messing around it but could not find the solution. I am getting an error:

```
raise NoReverseMatch(msg) django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

one of my html files about.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "all.css" %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bootstrap.css" %}" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static "style.css" %}">
  <title>Online yuridik xizmatlar</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="navbar-brand"><i class="fas fa-balance-scale"></i></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="nav-link">Bosh sahifa</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{% url 'about' %}" class="nav-link">Biz haqimizda</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{% url 'contact' %}" class="nav-link">Biz bilan bog'laning</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="about-banner">
    <div class="container text-center py-5 text-white">
      <h1>Bizning kompaniyamiz haqida</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis aut doloribus dolores minus</br> voluptatibus in?</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="about-content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row py-5">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h3>What we do</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dolorem, doloremque
            quidem quasi sint reiciendis rem voluptas atque ab nam non, qui excepturi unde optio cum,
            omnis necessitatibus recusandae a repellat.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dolorem, doloremque
              quidem quasi sint reiciendis rem voluptas atque ab nam non, qui excepturi unde optio cum,
              omnis necessitatibus recusandae a repellat.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="{% static 'assets/pexels-august-de-richelieu-4427430.jpg' %}" alt="" class="rounded-circle img-fluid about-img d-contents">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="our-staff bg-dark">
    <div class="container text-center text-white">
      <h2>Bizning jamoa</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="{% static 'assets/person1.jpg' %}" alt="" class="rounded-circle">
          <h3>Lobar Hakimova</h3>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="{% static 'assets/person2.jpg' %}" alt=""class="rounded-circle">
          <h3>Nigora Muxtorova</h3>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="{% static 'assets/person3.jpg' %}" alt=""class="rounded-circle">
          <h3>Suxrob Murodov</h3>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="{% static 'assets/person4.jpg' %}" alt=""class="rounded-circle">
          <h3>Farhod Shodmonov</h3>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer id="main-footer" class="text-center p-4 bg-dark text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p>Copyright &copy;
          <span id="year"></span> Kahharoff</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>


  <script src="{% static "jquery.js" %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static "popper.js" %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static "bootstrap.js" %}"></script>

  <script>
    // Get the current year for the copyright
    $('#year').text(new Date().getFullYear());

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

models.py (I created a post creator model which admin can only create a post)

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
    
    STATUS = (
        (0,"Draft"),
        (1,"Publish")
    )
    
    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
        updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
        content = models.TextField()
        created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ['-created_on']
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

**app/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView
from .models import Post



class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'


class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

**app/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from . import models

#Template tagging
app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^list/$', views.PostList.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
    url(r'<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(template_name='post_detail.html'), name='post_detail'),
]
```

project views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

class AboutPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'

class ContactPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'contact1.html'
```

project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls',namespace='blog')),
    #url(r'^blog/',include('django.contrib.auth.models.urls')),
    url(r'^about/', views.AboutPage.as_view(),name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.ContactPage.as_view(),name='contact'),
    
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You include your `blog.urls` with a namespace (`blog`) here:

```
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls',namespace='blog')),
```

Therefore the `url` tag should include the namespace as well:

```
{% url 'blog:index' %}
```

Comment: now when I create some post from the admin panel it is creating but when I move to the post page it is showing the error message:'raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '('birinchi-post-test',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/<slug:slug>/']'

Comment: `url(r'<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(template_name='post_detail.html'), name='post_detail')` error is pointing here

Comment: You are trying to mix Django 1.x style URL dispatcher (`url`) with the new style arguments (`<slug:slug>`). Use `path()` instead. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/ for the up-to-date documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much it helped me I was mixed the versions as you said.